# How do I set up correctly a camera?

Tags: interface

I've a Scene bought from Internet.

This scene has cameras, but I've set up a new one from the front of the object.

The problem is that when rendering (F12) It renders from top view (there is a camara from the scene in this position).

But I needed to render from the front, from the camara named "Camara".

Before rendering I press "0" to see the Camara's perspective and it is correct, but in rendering Camara changes to another camara from the scene: `Camara_4_Sc1`.

**I've set up my "Camara" in Scene panel**: but it renders from top (from camara from scene bought in Internet)

[image]

**Render from TOP** (wrong): Pressing F12 changes `Camara` to `Camara_4_Sc1`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering is possible only with an **active** camera. To do it you select it and press <kbd>CTRL + Numpad 0</kbd> or use the Menu as it is in the comment to make it active.

Comment: It should be CTRL + numpad 0. Regular 0 doesn't work. The menu path here is View -> Cameras -> Set Active Object as Camera